# Display Company if Company Sells Two Specific Products

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-pivot

I want to know which companies sell apples and oranges.
My data set is as follows

```
Name   Product

CompA  Apple
CompB  Banana
CompA  Orange
CompB  Apple
CompA  Taco
```

And I'd like the resulting pivot table (or really any reusable formula) to list something like

```
Name

CompA
```

Doesn't really matter as long as I get the list of names.
I tried doing a fancy pivot table and adding calculated fields, but they never worked.

Tried things like

```
=IF(Product="Apple",1,0) // Has Apple
=IF(Product="Orange",1,0) // Has Orange
=IF(AND('Has Apple' >= 1, 'Has Orange' >= 1),Name,"") // Has Apple and Orange
```

But no luck. The first two formulas never even worked.

My real data set is obviously different and much larger which is why I'm trying to do it through fancy formulas/pivot tables.

Comment: Is the list of companies dynamic? or are they always the same?

Comment: Dynamic! Different data might be loaded in at any time.

Comment: And the products you compare to are also dynamic, or always the same two? and what excel version do you have?

Comment: Correct, basically assume a random list of companies/products. Running the  mac version which for me is 16.16.*

Comment: You can turn this into a pivot, add companies as rows, product as filter (or slicer) and filter on "Apples" - the pivot update to show target companies with no formulas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert to Excel table then add another column and insert the following formula in C2

```
=AND(COUNTIFS([Name],[@Name],[Product],"Apple")>0,COUNTIFS([Name],[@Name],[Product],"Orange")>0)
```

It should autofill down. Create the pivottable and put the Formula field in the page field area and filter on True

[image]

Comment: I don't think this would work. I wouldn't be able to tell if CompA had Apple AND Orange. Just if it had one or the other.

Comment: Sorry I missed the And